# Triggered movement script for triggered objects

Tags: c#, unity3d

I am trying to more or less perfect a movement script that activates when "triggered" by another object. Below I have the code for both the triggering object as well as the object being triggered.

I tried to provide summary data to make it obvious what I'm doing, but what can I improve here? And please don't tell me "everything". I am new to Unity3d, and am very much still in the process of learning. I need to know specifics on what I can do and work to improve my skill. Also, I know the models aren't the best thing ever made, but I'm also new to Blender!

### Button / trigger object as well as its inspector

[image: Button or Trigger Object]
[image: Trigger Object In Inspector]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PropActivateMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    #region Public Declarations
    private enum ActivationStyle 
    {
        OnTriggerEnter = 0,
        OnActionButton = 1,
        OnTriggerOccupy = 2
    }
    public Animator animActivation = null;
    #endregion

    #region Public Declarations
    public string AnimationActivationName = "PushTrigger";
    /// <summary>
    /// The audio source when this object is activated.
    /// </summary>
    public AudioSource AudioActivated = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// The object to move.
    /// </summary>
    public PropMovement ObjectToMove = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// The direction to move this object.
    /// A value greater than or equal to 1 moves in a positive direction.
    /// A value less than or equal to -1 moves in a negative direction.
    /// A value equal to 0 alternates direction.
    /// </summary>
    public int ObjectMovementDirection = 0;
    /// <summary>
    /// The style of activation for this object.
    /// A value of 0 activates the object OnTriggerEnter.
    /// A value of 1 activates the object only once pressing the action button while inside of the triggering location.
    /// A value of 2 activates the object OnTriggerEnter and deactivates the object OnTriggerExit.
    /// </summary>
    public int StyleOfActivation = 0;
    public bool IsActivated = false;
    #endregion

    private void Start() {
        AudioActivated = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    }

    #region Private Methods
    private void OnTriggerEnter () {
        Debug.Log ("Trigger area entered");
        if (StyleOfActivation == (int)ActivationStyle.OnTriggerEnter)
        {
            ActivateMovement();
        }
        else if (StyleOfActivation == (int)ActivationStyle.OnTriggerOccupy)
        {
            ActivateMovement();
        }
        animActivation = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit () {
        Debug.Log ("Trigger area exited");
        if (StyleOfActivation == (int)ActivationStyle.OnTriggerOccupy)
        {
            ObjectToMove.SwitchMovement();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay () {
        if (StyleOfActivation == (int)ActivationStyle.OnActionButton)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Action button pressed.");
                ActivateMovement();
            }
        }
    }
    public void ActivateMovement () {
        Debug.Log ("Activating prop movement.");
        if (AudioActivated != null)
        {
            AudioActivated.Play ();
        }
        if (animActivation != null)
        {
            int currentState = Animator.StringToHash ("PushTrigger");
            animActivation.Play(currentState);
        }

        if (ObjectMovementDirection == 0)
        {
            ObjectToMove.SwitchMovement();
        }
        else if (ObjectMovementDirection > 0)
        {
            ObjectToMove.MovePositive();
        }
        else if (ObjectMovementDirection < 0)
        {
            ObjectToMove.MoveNegative();
        }
        IsActivated = !IsActivated;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

### Door to be triggered as well as its inspector

[image: Door to be Triggered]
[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PropMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    #region Private Declarations
    private Transform objTransform = null;
    private float startTime = 0.0f;
    private float DistanctToTravel = 0.0f;
    private Vector3 posObjectStart;
    private Vector3 posObjectCurrent;
    private bool isMovingPositive = false;
    #endregion

    #region Public Declarations
    /// <summary>
    /// The audio during movement.
    /// </summary>
    public AudioSource AudioDuringMovement = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// The object is currently moving.
    /// </summary>
    public bool isMoving = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// The position in which the object should stop movement.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 posObjectEnd;
    /// <summary>
    /// Smoothing factor of the doors movement.
    /// </summary>
    public float objectSmoothing = 1.0f;
    #endregion

    private void Start () {
        objTransform = transform;
        posObjectStart = transform.position;
    }

    #region Private Methods
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if (posObjectEnd.x == 0.0f)
        {
            posObjectEnd.x = posObjectStart.x;
        }
        if (posObjectEnd.y == 0.0f)
        {
            posObjectEnd.y = posObjectStart.y;      
        }
        if (posObjectEnd.z == 0.0f)
        {
            posObjectEnd.z = posObjectStart.z;
        }
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (objTransform != null)
        {
            if (isMoving)
            {
                posObjectCurrent = objTransform.position;
                if (isMovingPositive)
                {
                    if (transform.position != posObjectEnd)
                    {
                        StartCoroutine(MoveObject(posObjectCurrent, posObjectEnd));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isMoving = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!isMovingPositive)
                {
                    if (transform.position != posObjectStart)
                    {
                        StartCoroutine(MoveObject(posObjectCurrent, posObjectStart));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isMoving = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AudioDuringMovement.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveObject(Vector3 moveFrom, Vector3 moveTo){
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * objectSmoothing;
        float smoothing = distCovered / DistanctToTravel;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(moveFrom, moveTo, smoothing);
        yield return null;
    }

    private IEnumerator PlayMovementAudio() {
        AudioDuringMovement.Play();
        yield return null;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Moves object in a positive direction.
    /// </summary>
    public void MovePositive(){
        StartCoroutine (PlayMovementAudio ());
        startTime = Time.time;
        isMovingPositive = true;
        isMoving = true;
        DistanctToTravel = Vector3.Distance (posObjectEnd, posObjectStart);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Moves object in a negative direction.
    /// </summary>
    public void MoveNegative(){
        StartCoroutine (PlayMovementAudio ());
        startTime = Time.time;
        isMovingPositive = false;
        isMoving = true;
        DistanctToTravel = Vector3.Distance (posObjectStart, posObjectEnd);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Moves object in a opposite direction of its previous movement.
    /// </summary>
    public void SwitchMovement(){
        if (isMovingPositive)
        {
            MovePositive();
        }
        else
        {
            MoveNegative();
        }
        isMovingPositive = !isMovingPositive;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you don't use public fields in most circumstances. See [this link](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx) for more information.

I am aware that Unity's inspector will not serialize properties, but there's a nifty way around it, you can use this pattern:

```
[SerializeField]
private float backingFloat;

public float PropertyFloat
{
    get
    {
        return backingFloat;
    }
    set
    {
        backingFloat = value;
    }
}
```

The 'SerializeField' attribute will expose the private field in the inspector. This way you can still set (and change at runtime) the value of a field using Unity's inspector, and also retain the joys of properties.

The only caveat you must remember is that any setter logic you write will **not** be applied to changes you make in the inspector, because the value will be written straight to the backing field. It's a minor pain for debugging and development, but will not affect a published game.

If you find the pattern a bit much, I recommend creating a snippet using your favourite IDE (it's possible in both MonoDevelop and Visual Studio, at the very least) to automatically create such properties for you.

Comment: Ahh! I wanted to do that per the standard class construction, but couldn't figure out how to make the property visible! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Standard C# naming convention for public fields is `PascalCase`.
2. You are mixing bracing styles. Sometime you put the starting `{` on a new line and sometimes you put it at the end of the previous line. Be consistent.
3. In `PropActivateMovement` you have a bunch of public fields (which has already been mentioned as something you should avoid). Some of these fields are initialized with `null` yet you have code which relies on them not being `null`. If you have properties which have to have been initialized properly for your operations on the class to make sense then you should have a constructor which requires these as parameter possibly garnished with a `ArgumentNullException` in case someone passes in `null`. Some something along these lines:

   ```
   public class SomeClass 
   {
       public SomeClass(Foo foo, Bar bar)
       {
           if (foo == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
           if (bar == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");

           ...
       }
   }
   ```
4. `MovePositive` and `MoveNegative` contain almost the same code. This should be extracted into a common method instead.
5. In the `Update` method there is also a fair amount of code duplication in this part:

   > ```
   > if (isMovingPositive)
   > {
   >     if (transform.position != posObjectEnd)
   >     {
   >         StartCoroutine(MoveObject(posObjectCurrent, posObjectEnd));
   >     }
   >     else
   >     {
   >         isMoving = false;
   >     }
   > }
   > if (!isMovingPositive)
   > {
   >     if (transform.position != posObjectStart)
   >     {
   >         StartCoroutine(MoveObject(posObjectCurrent, posObjectStart));
   >     }
   >     else
   >     {
   >         isMoving = false;
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   This can be shortened to:

   ```
   var targetPosition = isMovingPositive ? posObjectEnd : posObjectStart;

   if (transform.position != targetPosition)
   {
       StartCoroutine(MoveObject(posObjectCurrent, targetPosition));
   }
   else
   {
       isMoving = false;
   }
   ```